# Python: pygame.mixer.music and unicode filenames

Tags: python, pygame

When you try to use pygame.mixer.music.open() with a filename string containing Unicode characters, it seems to throw a UnicodeEncodeError all the time:

```
File "C:\TestPlayer.py", line 43, in <module>
pygame.mixer.music.load(x)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 12-19: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

(lines broken for your viewing pleasure)

I checked for x's existance using os.path.exists(x), which returned True. Am I doing something wrong? If not, is it possible to manually fix pygame's mixer (which is a .pyd file)?

I'm using Python 2.6, and Pygame 1.9.1.

I forgot to add the file I tried opening is an mp3 file, but Pygame's website/wiki states pygame.mixer.music should work with those. In fact, it does, as long as the filename only contains ASCII characters.

Comment: Did you try decoding the filename before passing it?

Comment: I did, which didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a filename, open the file in a unicode compatible way and pass the file object to `pygame.mixer.music.load`

Comment: I tried using open() and passing that object, but it didn't seem to work. Am I doing it wrong again?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?  is the exception still thrown?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that; I got 'pygame.error: Module format not recognized', even when my filename is made up of just ASCII characters.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Did you open the file with the 'rb' binary mode flag?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows 7. Neither the r or rb flags proved successful.

Answer (score 0):

You tried

```
fle = open(filename, 'rb')
pygame.mixer.music.load(fle)
```

and

```
fle = open(filename, 'rb')
pygame.mixer.load(fle.read())
```

Or you could try, i dont know, something like

```
fle = open(filename, 'rb')
foo = fle.read()
pygame.mixer.load(fle.encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: FYI, from PEP8: If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than use an abbreviation or spelling corruption.  Thus "print_" is better than "prnt".  (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)